# target.getSource() not working for ui:inputNumber in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a component that displays several different input types, such as `ui:inputText` and `ui:inputNumber`.  Each input uses an `change="{!c.handleChange}"` attribute.

In my controller, the `handleChange` method then gets the value of the field.  However, `ui:inputNumber` fields aren't working.  The sandbox I'm in was just updated to Winter 18 - so wondering if this has something to do with it.

Here's my component snippet:

```
<ui:inputText change="{!c.handleChange}" />
<ui:inputNumber change="{!c.handleChange}" />
```

And in my controller:

```
handleChange : function(component,event,helper){
    // this works fine for all types except inputNumber
    console.log(event.getSource().get('v.value'));
}
```

Using the above, `ui:inputNumber` results in undefined.  I've also tried the old `event.target.value`, however `event.target` is undefined.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:  Adding entire component for context.  I'm dynamically generating the inputs based on a Fieldset, this component get spun up for each input that needs to be displayed.  It creates the input field based on the definitions passed to it.

Here's my component controller:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    // make the field component.
    $A.createComponent(component.get('v.fieldDefinition'), component.get('v.fieldAttributes'),function(cmp,status,error){
        if(component.get('v.fieldDefinition').startsWith('ui:')){
            // need to add a handler for standard ui: components.  custom components register them on their own.
            cmp.addHandler('change',component, 'c.handleFieldUpdated');

            // note: inputDate field does not support "onchange" events.
            if(component.get('v.callbacks') != null){
                for (var c in component.get('v.callbacks')){
                    var cb = component.get('v.callbacks')[c];
                    cmp.addHandler(c,component,cb);
                }
            }
        }
        component.set('v.cmp',cmp);
    });
},
handleFieldUpdated : function(component,event,helper){
    // event: FieldValueUpdated
    var evt = component.getEvent("valueUpdated");
    var val = event.getSource().get('v.value');
    console.log(event.getSource());
    console.log(val); // this is undefined for ui:inputNumber
    evt.setParams({
        fieldPath : component.get('v.fieldAttributes.fieldPath'),
        value : val
    });

    evt.fire();
}
```

})

And here's the component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="cmp" type="Aura.Component" />
    <aura:attribute name="fieldDefinition" type="string" />
    <aura:attribute name="fieldAttributes" type="object" />
    <aura:attribute name="callbacks" type="object" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="valueUpdated" type="c:FieldValueUpdated" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    {!v.cmp}
</aura:component>
```

EDIT: I've opened a case with Salesforce support to see if they can resolve this issue.  Case #17249103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to this, it's been sent to the R&D group via a support case.  Apparently they're able to reproduce this issue in both W18 and Summer 17 orgs, however I had this working in Summer 17 - and the switch to W18 broke the functionality.  Since they're saying it's not a regression issue, it's taking a lower priority.

For anyone at Salesforce looking at this, my case # is 17249103

I'm waiting to see if they're going to make a Known Issue of it for tracking.

Edit:  This was fixed in a patch release.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug to me.

After some investigations, it seems that the `ui:inputNumber` inherits from a component called: `ui:inputSmartNumber`

I think that they accidentally removed the `public` property of its `value` attribute.

Anyway, I was able to bypass this bug by using an another property of this component called `elements` which basically returns the `input` DOM element in its first index. So you can use the below code to get the value:

```
console.log(event.getSource().elements[0].value);
```

**EDIT**

Looks like this solution is not working if the component is not embedded in a record detail page.

Comment: Is there any formal documentation around event and what methods are available?  event.getSource().getLocalId(), event.getSource().get('v.value'), etc - I can't find any actual documentation around that.  Frustrating.

Comment: @JasonBenkert Sorry I couldn't find any. If this is helping, you have to tell you that the `event.getSource()` function basically returns the component itself. So besides the `getLocalId()` method, the `get()` method is supposed to return the available attributes of the component. Also, if you want to watch what are the availables properties, you can add a `console.log(event.getSource())` statement.

Comment: The workaround you provided isn't working for me.  I get a  [Cannot read property '0' of undefined] error.  Are you on W18?

Comment: Yes I am. I just changed your `ui:inputNumber` declaration to: `<ui:inputNumber change="{!c.handleChange}" />` because it wasn't compiling. The `onchange` event doesn't exist on this component. Besides this, I'm in the same configuration.

Comment: Could you add a `console.log(event.getSource())` to see if there is an `elements` property displayed as an array?

Comment: there is not.  I checked that first thing before posting the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65534/discussion-between-jason-benkert-and-martin-lezer).